# How do I externalize AGGrid's data altering mecanisms?

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

AGGrid provides some data altering mecanisms. For example, filters, pagination and sorting alter the data that is displayed.

It works great internally, however it does not seem to be possible to externalize such mecanisms. This would be very useful when using the server side row model and the source of the data is a store or a context, for example.

I have found some documentation and many posts/blogs about passing data from an external source to AGGrid, however I cannot find anything about updating such externalized data from AGGrid. In other words, I cannot externalize the filtering, pagination and sorting.

I found a workaround which implies firing a "filter event" to the parent from `getRows`. This is a workaround because this is not the purpose of `getRows`, and it comes with downsides. For example, I am unable to prevent `getRows` to cause a visual reloading of the data (which is completely normal, since reloading the data is the purpose of `getRows`).

```js
    const prevFilter = usePrev(gridRef.current?.api.getFilterModel(), {})

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!gridRef.current?.api) return

        gridRef.current.api.setGridOption("serverSideDatasource", {
            getRows: ({ success, request }: any) => {
                const filtersHaveChanged = JSON.stringify(prevFilter) !== JSON.stringify(request.filterModel)

                if (filtersHaveChanged) {
                    onFilterChange(request)
                    success({ rowData: [] }) // empty the table while the data is being updated using the new filters
                } else {
                    success({ rowData: rows }) // display the data when a data update is detected (whether it be from the table's logic, or from an external change)
                }
            }
        })
    }, [rows])
```

In my implementation of getRows, when AGGrid attempts to change the data due to a filter change, I hijack this attempt and fire an event, which goes somewhere higher in the hierarchy and results in a new fetching of the data. Meanwhile, as `getRows` requires me to pass some new data to the table to be displayed, I chose to empty the table (passing `[]` as the new `rowData`), as I prefer to have an empty table while loading over, which is visually better, but that is not the subject of this post.

Then the data is changed somwhere higher in the hierarchy. The component then re-renders as its prop `rows` changes. Therefore, a call to `setGridOption` assigns a new value to `getRows` and causes it to be called. This second call to `getRows` ends up in the `else` block and makes the table display the new data.

As you can see this is clearly a hacky workaround, as I could not find any standard way of externalizing the filter logic.

How can I externalize it in a standard way? Is it even possible?